# What is "Bonus DPS" feature for Vikings?

Tags: starcraft-2

On [teamliquid wiki page about viking](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Viking) there is two bonus features:

> Bonuses:       +4 vs Armored air
>
> Bonus DPS:     +2 vs Armored air

I understand that Viking do +4 more damage to armored units (comparatively to non-armored), but what does "Bonus DPS" mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are recalculating the DPS (damage per second) based on the bonus. So they do 4 more "damage per shot", which results in 2 more "damage per second" of sustained attacking.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it myself.

Viking has (against ground units, for example)

> Ground Attack:        12(+1)
>
> Ground DPS:       12(+1)

So against armored unit he makes bigger damage, so he DPS is also bigger...

so against usual unit it does 12 DPS, so against armored his DPS is 14.

:)

Comment: No, see Resorath's answer. You have to compare it as Damage (spent each X seconds) against DPS (spent in one second). The first one is more useful to know how much damage a bullet does, while the second one is more useful to compare the damage the unit does against other units.

Comment: For me both answers looks similar